# Как отловить клик на одном из элементов не меняя обработчик

Tags: javascript, html, css

При клике на чекбокс в консоль выводит input и label!  Возможно, как-то, не меняя обработчик на контейнере и не добавляя новых обработчиков получить либо input, либо label в консоли?

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.target));
```

```css
.check-material input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

.check-material {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.check-material input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background: #009688;
  border-color: #009688
}

.check-material input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  transform: scale(1.3)
}

.check-material label {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #CCC;
  border: 5px solid #7A7A7A;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s
}

.check-material label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s
}

.check-material label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://cbwconline.com/IMG/Codepen/Check.svg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .2s
}

.check-material label:active:before {
  background: #bfbfbf
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="check-material">
    <div>
      <input id="toggle-1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="toggle-1"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="toggle-2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
      <label for="toggle-2"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: может лучше `onchange` событие?

Comment: ThisMan, окей, но как-то тогда при срабатывание события onChange на инпуте, не вызывать клик на контейнере?

Comment: вы что хотите в итоге то получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментарии имелось в виду вот это:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e.target));
```

```css
.check-material input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

.check-material {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.check-material input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background: #009688;
  border-color: #009688
}

.check-material input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  transform: scale(1.3)
}

.check-material label {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #CCC;
  border: 5px solid #7A7A7A;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s
}

.check-material label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s
}

.check-material label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://cbwconline.com/IMG/Codepen/Check.svg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .2s
}

.check-material label:active:before {
  background: #bfbfbf
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="check-material">
    <div>
      <input id="toggle-1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="toggle-1"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="toggle-2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
      <label for="toggle-2"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```